# CollapsingToolbarLayout: statusBarScrim for expanded state?

Tags: android, statusbar, android-statusbar

I'd like to use a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to achieve an effect as in the following image:

[image]

To accomplish this, I first tried to set the status bar background color to a 30% opacity black in my theme. This works fine for the expanded state and achieves the intended effect.

However, I'd also like to use `@color/primaryColorDark` for the status bar as background when the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is collapsed. So I set `app:statusBarScrim` to `@color/primaryColorDark`, but because the status bar background is set to semi-transparent black in the theme, the color is darker than `@color/primaryColorDark`.

How do I set a status bar scrim that is used when the CollapsingToolbarLayout is expanded? `CollapsingToolbarLayout` has `app:statusBarScrim` for the collapsed state, but there is no such attribute for the expanded state. If I could do this, I can set the status bar to fully transparent and avoid the problem of the overly dark status bar in collapsed state.

Alternatively, is there a way to only set the status bar background to transparent when the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is collapsed?